# Auto refresh in mvc view Not partial view instead the main view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, auto

I have a mvc view which i need to refresh after every two seconds , basically i do not have only static data onto the view instead i have data which is coming from the db on each refresh i am using below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      location.reload(true);
    }, timeoutPeriod);
  }

   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />
```

Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");

but the issue is on IE and firefox it shows screen flickers so how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Enable browser caching and use jquery to update page dynamically through call back. Reload is just a very expensive and nit recommended approach here.

Comment: can you share any link of reference ?